# Unfolding nested RealmProxyObject looses values when nested level more than 3

Tags: android, realm

Here is my example.
I want to store in Realm some model of Week:

```
class Week extends RealmObject {
    RealmList<Day> days;
    int weekNum;
}

class Day extends RealmObject {
    RealmList<SmthNested> smthNested;
}

class SmthNested extends RealmObject {
    RealmList<SmthNestered2> smthNested2;
}

class SmthNested2 extends RealmObject {
    int value;
}
```

So when i do

```
Week week = realm.where(Week.class).equalTo("weekNum", weekNum).findFirst();
```

I get an object Week wrapped by realm proxy object. And as i can see it in debugger - fields are null, but getters work OK for all hierarchy. 
But when I pass this object some where else as element of Week. It loses all values after third level : SmthNested elements would have null values returned by getters.

Is it a bug or  just wrong way working with realm ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that's normal, according to the docs ([Debugging with Android Studio](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#android-studio-debugging))

> The debugger can provide misleading values depending on the debugging
>   view you’re using.

It mentions that you need to watch for the **getters** to show the correct values.

Comment: May be i poorly explained myself, but object return null via getters, after passing it some where(not in the debug mode).

Comment: Sorry, this is not an issue, i just had a another place which reseted my Week object awterwards((. Have to delete this question.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for everybody, i have my object reseted from outside.
This is an issue